# how to make a model doesn't contain duplicates in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I want an elegant way to make this work in rails 4:

```
# this is a neted_attribute for the model User
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible name, code

  # to make sure that when the user try to create a Category where exists
  # a category that has the same attributes it assigns
  # the current category to the existing one
  before_save do
    self = Category.where(name: name, code: code).first_or_initialize
  end
end
```

You don't need to be an expert to that this won't even parse. It is merely
an example to convey my idea.

Just to be clear I don't want validations (I'm very well aware of them).
And I can achieve this in many ways, but they would be
too hacky and complex for a general and common problem like this.

What I want is a way to enforce this feature in the model itself regardless
of its relation with other models.

Thanks in advance for your time and efforts.

Comment: This logic should probably live in the controller, or better, in a form object. There is a good railscast about form objects.

Comment: If it were to be implemented outside the model it would be more likely to produce unexpected bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. As you probably noted, Ruby does not allow you to assign to `self`, as the concept makes no sense. In the `before_save` filter, you could change `id` to match the existing record, but the `save` would fail because `ActiveRecord` would try to insert a new record in the database with the same `id` as an existing record, resulting in a database uniqueness violation.

Answer (score 0):

In a concern:

```
module CreateCategory
  def find_or_create_category(name, code)
    cat = Category.where(name: name, code: code).first_or_create
    self.categories << cat
    cat
  end
end
```

In user.rb:

```
include CreateCategory
```

When you create the category, use `@category = user.find_or_create_category(name, code)`

Comment: What you are suggesting is simply unneccessary function wrapping. I can simply solve this problem: '@user = User.new(params[:user}, category: Category.first_or_initialize(params[:category]))', but I want this property to be in the model itself, because unlike the example the category model could be involved with more than just the user model.

Comment: That is why you can include it as a module in any model that you would like. If you come up with a more modular approach, I would be interested to see.